# Display the table info in the next page using JSP

Tags: jsp

I am writing this web app in JSP as my college project.
When clicking the book button it redirected to a new page where the table information will be shown again. There could be multiple rows in the table each row having a book button. My question is how to retrive the row where the book button is clicked and show in next page. thank you
[Sreecnshot of the table where user will click the book button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFg4M.png)

Comment: post your code and ill show you how

Answer (score 0):

You need to accomplish two things:

1. Wrap your buttons in forms.
2. "Inject" entry/row identifier to each form.

So, usually your jsp code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Theme</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${themeList}" var="theme" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${theme.id}</td>
            <td>${theme.theme}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

You can see from the sample that on each iteration you have access to `theme.id` which is row identifier in the case.

You need to do similar with your code(find what is an identifier for every row). Then you need to wrap all buttons into forms:

```
    <td>
        <form action="/secondPage">
            <input type="hidden" value="${theme.id}">
            <input type="submit" value="Book">
        </form>
    </td>
```

Then on your page just retrieve the value from request parameters and find the data on your database -> display it.